# Closing Realm instance in RealmBaseAdapter

Tags: realm, listadapter, realm-base-adapter

In Realm's Java documentation [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances) it mentions it is best practice to:

> ... open a Realm instance in all your Activities and Fragments and close it again when the Activity or Fragment is destroyed.

However what happens if I want to do something like

```
public class HelperListAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<Helper> implements ListAdapter {
    //...
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    //...
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then where should I `close()` the realm instance in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs you linked quite specifically say that in order to maintain the lifecycle, you should create the Realm instance on the UI thread bound to the Activity lifecycle.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Even better - use a retained fragment to hold the Realm instance within the Activity and use the constructor and `onDestroy().

```
public class RealmFragment extends Fragment {
    Realm realm;

    public RealmFragment() {
         setRetainInstance(true);
         realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();
         realm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I've been reading on the docs...but the problem is I am using a `RealmBaseAdaptor<>` that as @Sung-Taek-Kim has mentioned is just a pattern to transfer data.

the bigger problem is thinking how to not read from `realm` here...

Comment: You just have to provide a result set from the Realm

Answer (score 0):

Java Adapter pattern is to provide means of transfer data between two entities, not for saving and reading right from it. I'd ask you look into [an example](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/tree/master/example) where Realm instance resides in Activity/Fragment and adapter is used to transfer values to Views.

Further, unclosed realm instances will consume memories and CPU cycles. Please consider close them as soon as you're done.